# What is the fastest way to find the last part of a url path?

Tags: java, regex

I have a url such as:

"http:/www.someco.com/news/2016-01-03/waterloo-station"

The url never contains a query string.

What is the cleanest way to extract the String "waterloo-station" ?

Of course I can use the following code:

```
url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1))
```

but I am not completely happy with it because it has to execute the search for the last index and then get the substring. I am wondering if there is a better way, (using regular expression?) to get the same result in a single step.

Of course the solution should be significantly faster when executed billions of times.

Comment: I'm calling massive premature optimization on this.

Comment: Why do you believe this could be made any faster?  One has to find the delimiter, and one has to construct a new string.  There's no way round that.

Comment: A regex is much more complex than just iterating over 17 elements of a char array. This is as fast as you can get, and is also as simple and as readable as you can get. It has 0 chance of being the cause of a performance problem in your application: if you must execute it billions of times, you need to read those URLs from the disk somehow, and that is many orders of magnitude slower than a substring.

Comment: I do not need to read them billions of times because I do not have billions of urls to read. I have many millions of them and I do not want to waste memory to save the result of the substring. I need to execute the substring many times because the algorithm needs it.

Comment: So are you effectively asking whether it's possible to construct a view into the original string, rather than constructing a new string?

Comment: I am just wondering if there is another method that finds the last occurrence  and instead of returning the index returns the remaining string... is this so unthinkable ?

Comment: @JohnHenry - Even if such a method exists, it won't be any faster than the above code.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I disagree. Even if the compiler optimizes, I hardly think that it will be so smart to avoid a double access to the string.

Comment: @JohnHenry: Can you describe an algorithm that wouldn't involve "double access"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that it can be improved. The short answer is that because the search for the last index is a simple operation, it can be implemented with a fast algorithm (directly in the String class!) and it would be difficult for a regular expression to be as fast as this. 
The second access to the String, as you can see, couldn't cost less: it is just the initialisation of the new String.

It could have been faster if there was a dedicated method implemented directly in the String class.

If you want more details, you can see by yourself the code in the JDK. Copied here for your convenience.

The following code is the implementation of the method lastIndexOf() in my JDK:

```
public int lastIndexOf(int ch, int fromIndex) {
    int min = offset;
    char v[] = value;

    int i = offset + ((fromIndex >= count) ? count - 1 : fromIndex);

    if (ch < Character.MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT) {
        // handle most cases here (ch is a BMP code point or a
        // negative value (invalid code point))
        for (; i >= min ; i--) {
            if (v[i] == ch) {
                return i - offset;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int max = offset + count;
    if (ch <= Character.MAX_CODE_POINT) {
        // handle supplementary characters here
        char[] surrogates = Character.toChars(ch);
        for (; i >= min; i--) {
            if (v[i] == surrogates[0]) {
                if (i + 1 == max) {
                    break;
                }
                if (v[i+1] == surrogates[1]) {
                    return i - offset;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Being implemented directly in the String class, it has access to its private members:

```
/** The value is used for character storage. */
private final char value[];

/** The offset is the first index of the storage that is used. */
private final int offset;

/** The count is the number of characters in the String. */
private final int count;
```

It is not working on substrings.
In the same time, the substring method is very fast in Java because it does not create a new array of char, but it simply creates a new String object changing the offset and the count:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
    if (beginIndex < 0) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
    }
    if (endIndex > count) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
    }
    if (beginIndex > endIndex) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex - beginIndex);
    }
    return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
        new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}

// Package private constructor which shares value array for speed.
String(int offset, int count, char value[]) {
    this.value = value;
    this.offset = offset;
    this.count = count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String.valueOf(Paths.get(file).getFileName())

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work because of "InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the fastest way to get the "filename", but it is pretty simple and fast:

```
var url = "http://www.someco.com/news/2016-01-03/waterloo-station";
var fileName = Path.of(new URI(url).getPath()).getFileName();
```